# GWT project: web browser hangs for some time when trying to load page

Tags: browser

I have a massive GWT project with using of spring framework. It's running on Jetty.
When I'm starting this web application - web browser goes to state 'Not Responding' for 10-15 second.

It's very odd, because I can't imagine reason why browser can hang.

Does any one know why such odd behaviour can occur ? Some calculations of javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that projects starts in in GWT debug mode, and when it's starting GWT actually validates and prepares java code for debugging. In that time browser is in 'hanged up' state.